# Is there a way to replicate the accuracy of Google maps on your own app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I was working on a project which needed to pinpoint the user's coordinates to within a few meters of accuracy. I noticed that the Google Maps app on my phone will HIGHLY accurately track my movement as I walk down the street, almost always to within a single meter.

In my own project, I did the following:

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In my MainActivity.java I have a function called `recenter` like so:

```
private void recenter(Location location) {
    LatLng user = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    userMarker.setPosition(user);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(user, 20));
}
```

And in my `onCreate` I make us of `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` like so (`locationListener` is triggered to call `recenter`):

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            recenter(location);
        }

        ...
    };
```

After I make sure permissions have been manually granted by the user, I run the following:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Nonetheless, my pin is usually several, I'd say about 10, meters off.
Is it possible to get Google maps level results on a home-made app?
And if not, anybody able to get more accurate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the android docs:

> Android offers two location permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. The permission you choose determines the
> accuracy of the location returned by the API. **You only need to request
> one of the Android location permissions**, depending on the level of
> accuracy you need:

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION – Allows the API

> to determine as precise a location as possible from the available
> location providers, including the Global Positioning System (GPS) as
> well as WiFi and mobile cell data.

Try removing every location in the manifest, except for the "fine course location" permission.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually in the middle of trying this. On top of this I was going to change my strategy to use the FusedLocationProvider recommended by Google, as the libraries I am using have since become outdated. Apologies for not being able to upvote, I only have 13 reputation at the time :(

Comment: No problem! I just upvoted your question, should you should have enough rep to vote now :)